# How to plot multiple sets of eigenvectors in the same plot in R?

Tags: r, pca, ggplot2

Below is an example with the iris dataset. I'm trying to find a way to plot the first two eigenvectors in the ellipse for each species together in the same plot.

```
data <- iris %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(pca = map(data, ~prcomp(.x[,-5], scale = TRUE)),
         scores = map(pca, ~data.frame(.x$x))) %>%
  select(-pca) %>%
  unnest()

ggplot(data, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, col = Species)) +
  stat_ellipse()
```

I tried extracting the individual eigenvectors for each species, but I think the rotation and intercepts are off. Failed attempt:

```
eigens <- iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(eigen = map(data, ~eigen(cor(.x))),
         slope1 = map_dbl(eigen, ~.x$vectors[1,1]/.x$vectors[2,1]),
         slope2 = map_dbl(eigen, ~.x$vectors[1,1]/.x$vectors[1,2]))

ggplot(data, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, col = Species)) +
  stat_ellipse() +
  geom_abline(data = eigens, aes(intercept = 0, slope = slope1, color = Species)) +
  geom_abline(data = eigens, aes(intercept = 0, slope = slope2, color = Species))
```

[image: plotting eigenvectors together]

Comment: This looks like more of a programming question and so off-topic here.